# How split vector on chunks with variable size in R?

Tags: r

Let see the example

There is a vector of 100 dates of observations

```
 x <- 1:100
```

I would like to split it on chunks related to the percent of original data ("sum" should be "1").

```
  p <- c(30, 25, 20, 15, 10)
  sum(p)
```

The "p" is a percent of original data (30% and etc.)

The desired output is chunks of observations with variable size:

```
 result <- list(list(1:30), list(31:55), list(56:75), list(76:90), list(91:100))
```

This is useful for parallel processing when the first chunks have bigger size than the next ones.

Comment: @akrun [You can instantly reopen any question closed as a duplicate that was originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/220122). [if you have a gold tag-badge for a tag associated with a question that's been closed as a duplicate, you can edit the duplicate links to replace, add, remove or re-arrange them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291824/220122).

Comment: @Henrik I am aware of that and it is a trap to flag it

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `split`

```
result1 <- lapply(unname(split(x, rep(seq_along(p), p))), function(x) list(x))
identical(result, result1)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or another option with `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) list(x:y), c(1, cumsum(p)[-length(p)]+1), cumsum(p) )
```